# Stop js function if another onclick event happends

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this function which loads the content of different `.php` pages depending on which button i click. But if I click on one of the buttons and the `.php` content isn't fully loaded and i then click on another one, then the old content still loads in when its done.

So I want to stop the function from finishing if the user decides to click on another button

```html
<div class="wdc-background">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="wdc-table-menu">
        <ul id="menu_wdc">
            <li><a class="wdc-btn active" href="#" onclick="loadTab('wdc_tab')">WDC</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#" onclick="loadTab('history_tab')">History</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#" onclick="loadTab('components_tab')">Components</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wdc_tab_fields" class="wdc_tab_fields"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=loadTab('wdc_tab');
</script>
```

The js function, which somehow should detect if it should stop loading if another button has been clicked, so it doesn't load the content of it all.

```js
function loadTab(tab) {
    console.log(tab);
    menu_functionallity();
    wdc_tab_fields = document.getElementById("wdc_tab_fields");
    wdc_tab_fields.innerHTML = "<img class='svg-color' style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; padding: 2rem;' src='../images/svg/grid.svg'/>";
    var request_object = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (tab == "") {
        wdc_tab_fields.innerHTML = "ERROR - Query is empty";
        return false;
    }

    request_object.open("GET", "../pages/wdc-pages/" + tab + ".php", true);
    request_object.send();
    request_object.onreadystatechange = () => {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState
        if (request_object.readyState !== request_object.DONE) {
            wdc_tab_fields.innerHTML = "ERROR - " + request_object.readyState + ": " + dict[request_object.readyState];
            return false;
        }
        if (request_object.status != 200) { // Normal http request return status
            wdc_tab_fields.innerHTML = "ERROR - Loading " + tab + " content";
            return false;
        }

        wdc_tab_fields.innerHTML = request_object.responseText;
        if (tab == "wdc_tab") {
            loadCanvas("wdc_canvas");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just disable buttons when one is clicked, and then re-enable them once the page is loaded?

Comment: @Andy aah thats actually one solution yes ;)

Comment: Also you really do not need the `ActiveXObject` check.... that has not been needed in years.

Comment: Also: perhaps look into how modern JS works using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). It's much easier to understand.

Comment: You can just `abort()` the XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do a check to see if the tab has been changed

```js
var activeTab;
function loadTab(tab) {
    activeTab = tab;
    ....
    request_object.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (activeTab != tab) return;
      ...
```

or you can abort the call if active

```js
var request_object;
function loadTab(tab) {
  if (request_object && !request_object.DONE) request_object.abort();
  request_object = new XMLHttpRequest()
```